# SQL: Running Total of Occurrences

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

I am using Metabase with a PostgreSQL implementation.

[image: Running Count of Occurrences]

I'd like to achieve the outcome in the photo. I wish to include a column that counts how many times a field has occurred above. It should include the current instance as well.

Other examples I've seen have simply counted total occurrences. As I am ordering by date, I do not wish to count occurrences that happen after the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions in Postgres:

```
select name, date, row_number() over (partition by name order by date) as seqnum
from t;
```

You probably also want `order by date` at the end of the query to guarantee that the results are in date order.

Comment: This is working for me! ... with one small issue. There are some cases where multiple instances occur on the same day. I do not understand why it may list:
David - 2,
David - 1,
David - 3...

`order by date, seqnum`seems to address it though.